# Median of medians algorithm: why divide the array into blocks of size 5

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, array-algorithms

In median-of-medians algorithm, we need to divide the array into chunks of size 5. I am wondering how did the inventors of the algorithms came up with the magic number '5' and not, may be, 7, or 9 or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you'll check "Proof of O(n) running time" section of wiki page for [medians-of-medians algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Proof_of_O.28n.29_running_time):

> The median-calculating recursive call does not exceed worst-case linear behavior because the list of medians is 20% of the size of the list, while the other recursive call recurses on at most 70% of the list, making the running time
>
> [image]
>
> The O(n) term c n is for the partitioning work (we visited each element a constant number of times, in order to form them into n/5 groups and take each median in O(1) time).
>   From this, using induction, one can easily show that
>
> [image]

That should help you to understand, why.

Comment: This proves the O(n) running time of using 20%, it doesn't disprove the O(n) running time of some other percentage (if some other percentage was also O(n), it doesn't justify the choice of 20% above the other).

Answer (score 6):

The number has to be larger than 3 (and an odd number, obviously) for the algorithm. 5 is the smallest odd number larger than 3. So 5 was chosen.

Comment: It doesn't have to be larger tan 3 (and odd), see my answer below.

Comment: Yes, but that is a different algorithm. It's only a slight variation of the algorithm OP was asking about - but it's still a different algorithm. OP asked "why in this specific algorithm do we need to use blocks of 5", and not "is there a variant on this algorithm where we could use smaller blocks". They were trying to understand how something was calculated rather than trying to find if there's something different that can do it better.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use blocks of size 3 or 4, as shown in the paper [Select with groups of 3 or 4](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/faculty/ad/select.pdf) by K. Chen and A. Dumitrescu (2015). The idea is to use the "median of medians" algorithm twice and partition only after that. This lowers the quality of the pivot but is faster.

So instead of:

```
T(n) <= T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + O(n)
T(n) = O(nlogn)
```

one gets:

```
T(n) <= T(n/9) + T(7n/9) + O(n)
T(n) = Theta(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

See this explanation on [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/median-finding-algorithm/#citation-2). Basically, five is the smallest possible array we can use to maintain linear time. It is also easy to implement a linear sort with an n=5 sized array. Apologies for the laTex:

> Why 5?
>
> The median-of-medians divides a list into sublists of length five to
> get an optimal running time. Remember, finding the median of small
> lists by brute force (sorting) takes a small amount of time, so the
> length of the sublists must be fairly small. However, adjusting the
> sublist size to three, for example, does change the running time for
> the worse.
>
> If the algorithm divided the list into sublists of length three, pp
> would be greater than approximately \frac{n}{3}   3 n ​      elements and
> it would be smaller than approximately \frac{n}{3}  3 n ​    elements.
> This would cause a worst case \frac{2n}{3}  3 2n ​       recursions,
> yielding the recurrence T(n) = T\big( \frac{n}{3}\big) +
> T\big(\frac{2n}{3}\big) + O(n),T(n)=T(  3 n ​   )+T(  3 2n ​    )+O(n),
> which by the master theorem is O(n \log n),O(nlogn), which is slower
> than linear time.
>
> In fact, for any recurrence of the form T(n) \leq T(an) + T(bn) +
> cnT(n)≤T(an)+T(bn)+cn, if a + b < 1a+b<1, the recurrence will solve to
> O(n)O(n), and if a+b > 1a+b>1, the recurrence is usually equal to
> \Omega(n \log n)Ω(nlogn). [3]
>
> The median-of-medians algorithm could use a sublist size greater than
> 5—for example, 7—and maintain a linear running time. However, we need
> to keep the sublist size as small as we can so that sorting the
> sublists can be done in what is effectively constant time.