# Median of Medians using blocks of 3 - why is it not linearic?

Tags: time-complexity, median-of-medians

I understand why, in worst case, where T is the running time of the algorithm, that using the median of medians algorithm with blocks of size three gives a recurrence relation of

> T(n) = T(2n / 3) + T(n / 3) + O(n)

The [Wikipedia article for the median-of-medians algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) says that with blocks of size three the runtime is not O(n) because it still needs to check all n elements. I don't quite understand this explanation, and in my homework it says I need to show it by induction.

How would I show that median-of-medians takes time Ω(n log n) in this case?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095753/median-of-medians-algorithm-why-divide-the-array-into-blocks-of-size-5

Comment: It is, but you have to use "median of medians" twice, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39288513/1037407

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework problem I'm going to let you figure out a rigorous proof of this result on your own, but it might be helpful to think about this one by looking at the shape of the recursion tree, which will be something like this:

```
                      n                         Total work: n
      2n/3                        n/3           Total work: n
4n/9        2n/9             2n/9      n/9      Total work: n
```

Essentially, each node's children collectively will do the exact same amount of work as the node itself, so if you sum up the work done across the layers, you should see roughly linear work done per level. It won't be *exactly* linear work per level because eventually the smaller call starts to bottom out, but for the top layers you'll see this pattern hold.

You can formalize this by induction by guessing that the runtime is something of the form cn log n, possibly with some lower-order terms added in, but (IMHO) it's more important and instructive to see where the runtime comes from than it is to be able to prove it inductively.

Comment: Downvoter - can you explain what I can do to improve this answer?

Comment: Hey is it possible for you to share the induction proof.

Answer (score -1):

If we add the fractional parts of T(2n/3) and T(n/3), get T(n). Then, using the Master theorem, we have n^(log_(b)(a)) = n^(log_(1)(1)) = n. We also have f(n) = O(n). So n^(log_(b)(a)) = O(n) = Theta(f(n)), thus Case 2 of the Master theorem applies. Thus T(n) = Theta(n^(log_(b)(a)) * log(n)) = Theta(n*log(n)).

Comment: This math is incorrect. You can't "add" T(n / 3) + T(2n / 3) to get T(n), since that ignores the extra work being done (it coincidentally happens to work in this case, but isn't in general valid). Similarly, you can't apply the Master Theorem to a recurrence relation with a term of the form T(n) in it, since that recursion never terminates. Additionally, log_1 1 is not n; it's undefined because 1^k = 1 for any choice of k.